# Server Error 500 potential duplicate script error?

Tags: php

I'm really confused here. I have a PHP script which keeps returning an error whenever I include the file.

```
<?php
  # Pre-requires
  include 'default.php';
  $db = doDB();
  # Main
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ReleaseNotes";
  $stmt = $db->query($sql);
?>
```

I have another file kinda like this when I include it.

```
<?php
  # Pre-requires
  include 'default.php';
  $db = doDB();
  # Main
  session_start();
  $cke = $_SESSION['LOGIN_COOKIE'];
  $usr = $cke;
 ?>
```

And it doesn't return the error.

Very confused here.

Comment: Yeah okay that fixed it wow I'm smart. :^)

Comment: Deep, add this as an answer =)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, fixed ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It easy. You should use **include_once()**